# Responsive header with text

Tags: css

HTML

```
<header class="hero-wrap">
  <div class="container no-gutters">
    <div class="message">
      <h1>Test header</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam mattis metus quis lacus venenatis ullamcorper. Ut ut interdum mauris. Phasellus varius nibh eu purus ultrices efficitur. Morbi egestas nibh massa, quis egestas ligula feugiat vitae. Quisque tincidunt sagittis facilisis. In imperdiet, nisl sed sodales aliquet, ante est bibendum est, et congue magna elit quis sapien. Vestibulum eleifend tellus nibh, ac ultrices risus rutrum vel. Sed feugiat tristique nulla, ut vestibulum nulla rhoncus eget. Mauris eget lorem at nulla vestibulum pharetra vitae et massa. Fusce bibendum hendrerit imperdiet. Fusce lobortis est vel rhoncus vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.hero-wrap{
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/kitten/kitten-5.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.message{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  float: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 70em){
  .hero-wrap{
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
  .message{
    float: right!important;
    padding: 75px 480px 85px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 800px;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 37.5em){
   .hero-wrap{
     padding-top: 20%;
   }

   .message{
    padding-right: 135px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
   }
}

.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.row.no-gutters [class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters [class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.container.no-gutters {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.container.no-gutters [class^="col-"],
.container.no-gutters [class*="col-"]{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

[image: Example Image]

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tkm0a0e5/1)

Used Bootstrap 3. The issues are :

1. the banner image and text on opacity background won't be stacked in blocks and the banner image doesn't show the center clearly as it is hidden behind the opacity background.

Clearly padding-top is not a good way for the banner in header as it is not helping to stack in block next to the background opacity.

2. Tried to make the background opacity wide after the half of the banner image and make it float with width: 800px for desktop mode. then when resized in smaller screen, it will be pushed down after the banner images in stack.

Question:

1. How to make banner responsive and set background opacity wide with float: right for the desktop mode?
2. Why is the banner image not showing as in the example image in the block enough to see what the picture is? How to make the text with background opacity stack after the banner image?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Joe can you find a better to explain your question.

Comment: @SleekGeek got it and i have put my questions.

Comment: I'm sorry I coudn't understand very well your question. I made you a fiddle just in case you are asking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tkm0a0e5/2/  (if it is, I will put it as an answer)

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez - thanks very much and yes that's what I wanted, but only thing is that text is cut off whether big screen size or smaller screen size. the background opacity's height at 50% is not right. It should be placed after the banner image in stack - see example image.

Comment: Well, to put it under the image I'm afraid you need a set height for the header. as there's the only way to move the text box perfectly under the image: http://jsfiddle.net/tkm0a0e5/3/ (in this case I've just used 500px)

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez yah it will do for now. many thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez -- sorry to trouble you again, but it is giving me issue because when i tested mobile screen size, background opacity will go through behind the navigation menu which is below banner image and text is cut off still :(